# Markdown の形式が CommonMark に切り替わりました

Tags: 討議, markdown

*この投稿は MSE でアナウンスされた [We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746) の投稿を翻訳、抜粋したものです。より詳しい内容 (切り替えの技術的背景など) については元の投稿を参照してください。*

---

スタック・オーバーフローを含め、Stack Exchange ネットワークのサイトでは投稿に Markdown を使用することができますが、このレンダリング部分が [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/) という形式に切り替えられました (2020-06-20 に切り替え完了)。

CommonMark がまだ存在しなかった時期には Stack Exchange での Markdown フレーバーの一部は独自に作成されていました。今回 CommonMark を採用したので、これらの独自な一部の機能を標準化された表記法 (web全体の他の場所でも広く知られた表記法) に置き換えます。

<sub>*編注:

Markdown では記号の後ろ、または前後に半角スペースが必要です。英語のような単語ごとに区切る言語とは違い日本語では基本的にスペースを挟まないので、例えば "見出し" 記法でスペースの無い投稿をいくつか見かける時があります。

以前は多少ルーズな記述でも Markdown としてレンダリングされていましたが、今回の切り替えによって厳密な記法を心掛ける必要があります。*</sub>

最も顕著な変更は、リスト、ネストされたリスト、見出し、引用です。

**リスト**:
ネストされたリストを作成するときは、ネストされたリストアイテムまたは段落を適切なスペースでインデントする必要があります。以前は1つのスペースで十分でしたが、今後はリストの種類に応じて、追加のスペースをいくつか追加する必要があります。

リストアイテムの段落の一部を作成するには、段落の前にスペースを1つ追加するだけで十分でした

```
* this is a list item

 that goes on here
```

CommonMark の場合、段落は親のテキストと一致する必要があるため、いくつかのスペースが必要です:

```
* this is a list item

  that goes on here
```

**見出し**:
今後は、先頭の `#` 記号の後ろにスペースを追加する必要があります。

```
#this was cool before
```

```
# this is what's cool now
```

**引用**:
以前は、ブロック引用としてマークされた2つの行の間に空行があっても、1つの大きなブロック引用として扱われていました。今後は、空の行にも明示的に `>` を挿入しない限り2つの異なるブロック引用として扱われます:

```
> old blockquotes  

> with multiple lines
```

```
> new blockquotes
> 
> with multiple lines
```

**インデントされたコードブロックの強調表示**:
最も大きな変更は、インデントされたコードブロックと、言語を宣言してコードを強調表示する機能です。

コードブロックで構文の強調表示に使用する言語を宣言する場合は、インデントされたコードブロックではなく、コードフェンス表記を使用します。引き続きインデントされたコードブロックを使用することはできますが、優先言語を明示的に宣言することはできません。

これまでは、インデントされたコードブロックの言語を宣言するために以下の様な記述を行うことができました。

```
<!-- language: python -->

    def hello():
        print("Hello, World");
```

将来的に、これは機能しなくなります。代わりにコードフェンス表記を使用して、コードブロックの言語を明示的に宣言できます:

````
``` python
def hello():
    print("Hello, World");
```
````

これは CommonMark 標準が提案している方法であり、他のWebサイトでも利用されている方法です。従来の `<!-- language: lang -->` コメントによる構文の強調表示に慣れ親しんだユーザーがいる事も把握しています。As we’re adopting new Markdown parsers, we want to avoid patching quirky behavior into those parsers when there’s an official, standards-compliant way of achieving the same goal that we can adopt with no extra effort.

投稿に関連付けられたタグに基づく構文の強調表示も引き続き機能します。構文の強調表示で現在動作する完全なリストや概要は [こちらの投稿を参照してください (英文)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) 。今後はこちらの投稿を更新していきます。
<sub>訳注: [構文の強調表示に関する日本語訳の説明はこちら](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2709)</sub>

---