# スタックオーバーフローで使えるHTMLタグ一覧はありますか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案

スタックオーバーフローは質問や回答に[マークダウン](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)を使えます。
Markdownの仕様により、自由に**HTMLタグと併用**することもできます。

ただし**すべての**HTMLタグが使える訳ではありません。そうしないと[XSS](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0)攻撃の温床になってしまいます。
スタックオーバーフローで許可されているHTMLタグのホワイトリストはありますか？

[←よくある質問の目次に戻る](/q/1484)

---

<sup>この投稿はStack Exchangeの[メタ質問](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)を翻訳したものです。</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 前書き

この回答はStack Exchangeの[メタ回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909)を翻訳して加筆修正したものです。
前提としてHTMLタグよりも**Markdownを優先**して利用しましょう。
`<kbd>`タグなどMarkdownで実現できない表現の場合、適切な用途でご活用ください。

参考リンク:
[Markdown や HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)
[Markdown ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

## 使用可能なHTMLタグ

Stack Exchangeでは下記の**安全と認めたHTMLタグのサブセット**のみ利用可能です。

| タグ | タグの定義 | 構文例 | 表示例 | Markdown記法 | 備考 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `<a>` | ハイパーリンク | `<a href="/q/331">練習場</a>` | [練習場](/q/331) | `[練習場](/q/331)` | 構文は後述 |
| `<b>` | 太字 | `<b>bold</b>` | **bold** | `**bold**` | `<h1>-<h3>`, `<em>` または`<strong>`を優先して使うこと。 太字はどうしても必要な時のみ利用すべき |
| `<blockquote>` | 別ソースからの引用 |  |  | 行頭の`>` |  |
| `<code>` | プログラムコード | `<code>Hello World!</code>` | `Hello World!` | `Hello World!` |  |
| `<del>` | 打消し線 | `<del>delete</del>` | <del>delete</del> | `-delete-` | 修正削除した要素を示す |
| `<dd>` | タグの子要素。 定義語の説明文 |  |  |  |  |
| `<dl>` | 定義語のリスト |  |  |  |  |
| `<dt>` | タグの子要素。 定義語 |  |  |  |  |
| `<em>` | 強調 | `<em>emphasis</em>` | *emphasis* | `*emphasis*` |  |
| `<h1>` `<h2>` `<h3>` | 見出し | `<h1>大見出し</h1>` `<h2>中見出し</h2>` `<h3>小見出し</h3>` |  | `# 大見出し` `## 中見出し` `### 小見出し` |  |
| `<i>` | イタリック体(斜体) | `<i>italic</i>` | *italic* | `*italic*` |  |
| `<img>` | 画像 | `<img src="/favicon.ico" alt="icon"/>` | [image: icon] | `![icon](/favicon.ico)` | 構文は後述 |
| `<kbd>` | 入力 | `<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>` | <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> |  | 主にキーボード入力で使用 |
| `<li>` | リスト項目。 `<ol>`または`<ul>`の子要素。 |  |  |  | Markdownは行頭の`1.` や`+` で表現 |
| `<ol>` | 数字付きリスト |  |  | 行頭の`{数字}.` |  |
| `<p>` | 段落 | `<p>paragraph</p>` | paragraph |  |  |
| `<pre>` | 整形済みテキスト | `<pre>preformatted</pre>` | ``` preformatted ``` | ``` preformatted ``` | 正確には`lang-none`相当。 [シンタックスハイライト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2708)も参照のこと |
| `<s>` | 打消し線 | `<s>strike</s>` | <s>strike</s> | `-strike-` | Markdownまたは`<del>`の利用を推奨 |
| `<sup>` | 上付き文字 | `<sup>superscript</sup>` | <sup>superscript</sup> |  | 脚注などに使う |
| `<sub>` | 下付き文字 | `<sub>subscript</sub>` | <sub>subscript</sub> |  |  |
| `<strong>` | すごく強調 | `<strong>strong</strong>` | **strong** | `**strong**` | 表示上は`<em>`と変わらない |
| `<strike>` | 打消し線 | `<strike>strike</strike>` | <strike>strike</strike> | `-strike-` | Markdownまたは`<del>`の利用を推奨 |
| `<ul>` | 数字なしリスト |  |  | 行頭の`+` や`-` |  |
| `<br>` | 改行 | `改<br>行` | 改 行 |  |  |
| `<hr>` | 水平線 |  |  | `---` |  |

### ノート

HTMLタグが使える代わりに、**「<」を表示したい場合はエスケープする必要があります。**
エスケープする方法は、`>`をコード表記(4文字インデントするかバッククォートで囲む)する方法と`&lt;`を使う方法があります。

## 使用可能なタグ属性

### img属性

`<img>`タグでは下記の属性が使えます。
しかしモバイル向けテーマでは`width`の最大値が90%に強制され、それに伴ってモバイル環境では`height`も指示通りに伸縮されないかもしれません。

**属性の並び順に要注意！**`height`の前に`width`を記載するなど、順番を変えるとタグが無効化されます！

- src="画像のソース"
- width="100" (`999`まで。'px'は記述しないでください)
- height="100" (`999`まで。'px'は記述しないでください。上記の説明も参考にしてください)
- alt="代替テキスト"
- title="タイトル"

Markdownでサイズ調整する構文は[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14675913)を参照してください。

### a属性

`<a>`タグでは下記の属性が使えます。

- href="リンク先"
- title="タイトル"

`href`属性は下記の仕様です。

- 使用可能

  - 絶対URL(`https://ja.stackoverflow.com/`など)
  - 相対URL、プロトコル相対URL(`/q/31`, `//stackexchange.com/users/`など)
- 使用不可

  - 特殊な記法(例えば `#31` のようなもの)
  - HTTP、HTTPS以外のプロトコル(`pavascript`, `ftp`, `mailto`など)
    これらすべてのリンクがhrefに記述されている場合は、a属性が無効化されます。

## 重要Tips

- 上記にないHTMLタグは表示されません。
  プレビューには表示されるかもしれませんが、サーバ上で除去されます。
- タグが適用されるよう、正確に入力してください。
  このリストにあるタグは大文字小文字問わず使用できますが、それ以外の例外(属性の間に余分なスペースを入れる、シングルクォーテーションや引用符なしで属性を記述するなど)を含むタグは**無効化**されます。